# USB Product as both Host and Device without OTG

Tags: usb, usb-hub

Can a product behave as a USB Host in one setup and as USB Device in another setup without having USB OTG capabilities? My intuition says that this is not possible, since if it was, there would not be a need to develop OTG in the first place.

Comment: You can possibly do it with a USB-C cable/specification, but the earlier ones could not because of the differences in the host and device physical ports.

Comment: Other means of mode switching are possible, for example software based on many ARM SoC's even including the hubless Raspberry Pi models.  But in popular usage "OTG" sometimes means any role switchable device, not just those that switch roles in accordance with the OTG spec.

Comment: OTG is about *automatic* *standardized* switching. Sure, you can have a separate USB host port and a USB device port on the same plastic box. Maybe you can have a single USB-C port and a button which changes it between host mode and device mode (perhaps it has to reboot the device to change modes). The protocol doesn't care whether your device is *always* a host or whether it's only a host *this time*. But you will have a problem with the connectors because they do care.